# How to add dynamic comment to column with validation list?

Tags: vba, excel

Given an excel column with a validation list (dropdown).
How do I show a dynamic comment based on the selected option?

Thanks

Comment: A comment that changes its value based on the selected item of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The code below presumes that you have two overlapping named ranges. I called one `DropList` and the other one `Comments`. The `Comments` range comprises two columns, the first of which is declared as `DropList`. For example,

```
DropList = M2:M10 (any sheet)
Commments = M2:N10
```

`DropList` has all the items in your data validation. Enter `=DropList` in place of an actual list of items. This is to ensure that the list in your dropdown is guaranteed to be the same as what the code needs to find the comments. Write the comments to be associated with each dropdown item in the second column of the `Comments` range. The best place for the list is on a dedicated sheet that you keep hidden. Avoid placing it in the invisible part of another sheet because that would slow down your workbook.

Place the code below in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you have your dropdown. Observe that you can set any address for both the dropdown and the cell where you want the comment.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 03 Jan 2018

    Const DropColumn As String = "J"          ' location of drop-down
    Const CommentColumn As String = "K"       ' location of comment

    Dim DropVal As Variant
    Dim Commt As String
    Dim Test As Long

    With Target
        If .Column = Columns(DropColumn).Column Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Test = .Validation.Type
            If Err Then
                Err.Clear
            Else
                DropVal = .Value
                If Len(Trim(DropVal)) Then
                    Commt = Application.VLookup(DropVal, Range("Comments"), 2, False)
                    With Cells(.Row, Columns(CommentColumn).Column)
                        .ClearComments
                        .AddComment Commt
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code was modified to work on all cells with validation in the `DropColumn`

Comment: Thanks. Works for one cell. But I need this or a whole range (=column).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Variatus answer this code works for a longer ranger. Not only one cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DropVal As Variant
    Dim Commt As String


 Set KeyCells = Range("E1:E1000")

    With Target


        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
            DropVal = .Value
            If Len(Trim(DropVal)) Then
                Commt = Application.VLookup(DropVal, Range("Comments"), 2, False)
                With Range(Target.Address)
                    .ClearComments
                    .AddComment Commt
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```